# how to update duplicate rows in a column to a new values

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I will explain my problem briefly

have duplicate `rino` like below (actually this `rino` is the serial number in front end)

```
chqid rino branchid 
----- ---- -------- 
876   6    2        
14    6    2        
18    10   2        
828   10   2        
829   11   2        
19    11   2        
830   12   2        
20    12   2        
78    40   2        
1092  40   2        
1094  41   2        
79    41   2        
413   43   2        
1103  43   2        
82    44   2        
1104  44   2        
1105  45   2        
83    45   2        
91    46   2        
1106  46   2
```

here in my case I don't want to delete these duplicate `rino` instead of that I planned to update the `rino` having *max* date(*column not specified in the above sample actually a date column is there*) to the next `rino` number

what exactly I meant is :

if I sort out the above result according to the `max(date)` I will get

```
chqid rino branchid 
----- ---- -------- 
876   6    2        
828   10   2        
19    11   2        
830   12   2        
1092  40   2        
79    41   2        
413   43   2        
82    44   2        
83    45   2        
1106  46   2
```

<sup>(NOTE : total number of duplicate rows are **10** in `branchid=2`)</sup>

- the last entered  `rino` in the table for `branchid=2` is **245**
- So I just want to update the `10 rows`(Of column `rino`) with numbers starting from **246 to 255**( just added 245+10 like this `select lastno+  generate_series(1,10) nos from tab where cola=4 and branchid = 2 and vrid=20;`)

---

Expected Output:

```
chqid rino branchid 
----- ---- -------- 
876   246   2        
828   247   2        
19    248   2        
830   249   2        
1092  250   2        
79    251   2        
413   252   2        
82    253   2        
83    254   2        
1106  255   2
```

using [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql)

Comment: "if I sort out the above result according to the max(date) I will get".
After sorting 20 results you end up with only 10 of them. Either you're grouping them, or you're forgetting something.

Comment: @DeadlyJesus this is just a sample, FYI : am using `row_number()over (partition by rino::int  ) rn` to find out the dups

Comment: @DominicPretto you mean `row_number() over (partition by rino::int order by the_date_you_not_specified desc)`? So do you want to update those rows only, or you want to update all rows, which match those `rino` values also?

Comment: @pozs _want update all rows which matches  duplicate `rino`_

Comment: This is a bit of an FAQ, search for prior similar answers.

Comment: @CraigRinger I fig.out the solution

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution, am using dynamic-sql to solve my issue

```
do 
$$
declare
arow record;
  begin
    for arow in
            select chqid,rino,branchid from (
            select chqid,rino::int ,vrid,branchid ,row_number()over (partition by rino::int  ) rn
            from tab
            where vrid =20
            and branchid = 2)t
            where rn >1
loop
         execute format('
            update tab
            set rino=(select max(rino::int)+1  from gtab19 where  acyrid=4 and branchid = 2 and vrid=20)
            where chqid=%s
         ',arow.chqid);
end loop;
end;
$$;
```